# How to use SAP OpenUI5 to display table in frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am a newer to SAP OpenUI5. I want to display a table in frontend, here is my code:

Test.view:

```
    var oPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel("panel",{text:"Calculated Fields"});  
    var tableData = { 
        "teamMembers":[ 
            {"firstName":"Clark", "lastName":"Kent", "gender":"male", "occupation":"Superman","enable": true}, 
            {"firstName":"Donald", "lastName":"Duck", "gender":"male", "occupation":"a millionare","enable": true},
            {"firstName":"Marge", "lastName":"Simpson", "gender":"female", "occupation":"a housewife","enable": false},
            {"firstName":"Jane", "lastName":"Marple", "gender":"female", "occupation":"a detective","enable": true},
            {"firstName":"Tony", "lastName":"Stark", "gender":"male", "occupation":"Ironman","enable": true},
            {"firstName":"James", "lastName":"Kirk", "gender":"male", "occupation":"a Starfleet captain","enable": true},
            {"firstName":"Hermione", "lastName":"Granger", "gender":"female", "occupation":"a witch","enable": false}]};

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(tableData);
    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table("Table",{visibleRowCount: 7});

    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("FirstName",{
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "First Name" }), 
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextArea({ 
        value: "{firstName}",
        change: oController.handleTextAreaChange
            }), 
        width: "50px",
        name: "FirstName1"}));
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column("LastName",{
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Last Name" }), 
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextArea({
        value: "{lastName}",
        change: oController.handleTextAreaChange
            }), 
        width: "50px",
        name: "LastName1"}));
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: "Enable" }), 
        template: new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
            checked: "{enable}",
            change: oController.handleCheckBoxChange
            }), 
        width: "50px" }));

    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows("/teamMembers");

    oPanel.addContent(oTable);  
    return oPanel;
```

Test.controller:

```
sap.ui.controller("testtomcat.TestTomcat", {
    handleCheckBoxChange: function(oEvent){
        alert("ChackBox changed");
        },
    handleTextAreaChange: function(oEvent){
        alert("TextArea changed");
    }
}
```

The question is:

1. The function handleCheckBoxChange and handleTextAreaChange I have defined is only for the template. But I want to define a function which will be triggered when I change the value in textarea or checkbox, what can I do to achieve it?
2. Additionally, I want to check if the user input in the table is legal, in other words,I want to handle wrong user input, is there any better ideas to achieve it?

Please help me, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the template is specified to the column makes clones for each row. So if you change any of the textarea or checkbox , the handler will be triggered. 
Now when the handler is called you can play with the oEvent object.

```
handleTextAreaChange: function(oEvent){
        var oChangedTextArea  = oEvent.getSource();

         //Now you can handle the event 
         //for example
         var sGivenText  = oChangedTextArea.getValue();
         if(sGivenText.trim().length<30){
             alert("Minimum 30 characters required")
         }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I want to define different rules for the textareas, for example, for textarea1 the value has to be a number, for textarea2 it has to be true or false, for textarea3 is has to be some specific strings, etc. So is there a way to get the needed textarea directly(so I can define different handlers for different textareas instead of judging the user input in one templete function)? And futher more, is it possible to bind different controls to the model, and the controls are in one templete?

Comment: @LearnToDeath  check out following two links. These might help you. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0eac123bf7da42bb957cca46047e6556.html and https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8.html

Comment: Thank you again. I have checked that two links, but my case is different. By using templete I have already bound the controls with the model, but here is the question: I can't get each control object(because they are cloned from the templete automatically), which means I can't set a separate bindValue function or a formatter for it. I suppose SAPUI5 has a method to handle this situation but I just don't know. Please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: No. You can not bind separate value. But I am little confused about your context. Why do you need that?

Comment: In my case, I get a profile, which contains many parameters and values, from backend system. I want to display it in frontend, since the number of the parameters is large, I want to use aggregation binding to bind the parameters(in my code I use JSON model) to a table control. Besides, I also have a requirement that the user can change the parameters in frontend-that's why I use a TextArea control. So I have to judge if the user input is legal. If I can't bind separate value, is there a function in SAPUI5 which allows me to get the specific TextArea object  so I can set a handler for it?